# recalling blowfish encryption w/ salt from database at login

Tags: php, mysql, password-encryption

I'm obviously new to blowfish encryption to be asking this.  I believe to have one side of the equation figured out but cannot figure out how to login once the hash is in the DB.  I have the following for encrypting the password on registration:

```
    $blowfish_hash = "$2y$10$";
    $salt_length = 22;

    $salt = Generate_Salt($salt_length);
    $hash_combined = $blowfish_hash . $salt;

    $hash = crypt($password, $hash_combined);

    $password = $hash;
```

The `Generate_Salt()` function is as follows:

```
function Generate_Salt($length) {

  $unique_rndm_str = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
  $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_rndm_str);

  $mod_Base64_str = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string); 
  $salt = substr($mod_Base64_str, 0, $length);

    return $salt;
}
```

Once I register I get this nice long hash - great! but, when I go to login I'm unsure on how to call the hash to check against the given password: `$_POST['log_password'];`

Using md5 is was easy, I just encrypted this way `$password = md5($password);` and recalled this way `$password = md5($_POST['log_password']);` however reading up I realize that this is not a secure method.

I've been at this for hours, can anyone shed some light on this for me please?  Any help would be appreciated.

ep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier than you think. Just use the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead, it will do the call to the crypt() function and handles the generation of a safe salt.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST['password'], $existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: I figured out the other half on my own code & it works fine, however your suggested method is cleaner & requires less code.